# Windows 10 PRO не видит 30 портов USB

Tags: windows-10, usb

Необходимо работать в WINDOWS 10 PRO одновременно с 30-ю флешками (чтение и передача данных). Но как выяснилось в ОС стоит ограничение - одновременно система видит и работает только с 10-ю портами USB. Есть ли какое-то решение, чтобы увеличить работоспособность до 30ти портов?

Comment: если флешки подключаются все одновременно в надежде увеличить суммарную скорость чтения/записи, то огорчу: записать 30 флешек параллельно займёт столько же времени, как и запись этих 30 флешек последовательно, вставляя их по очереди в единственный USB-порт

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать хабы у которых 5 входов и 1 выход на юсб и так подключать последовательно в каждый порт, но можно будет столкнутся с нехваткой питания, это тоже учитывайте

Comment: Это мы уже прошли, это не дает нужной и эффективной работы. Если поочередно вставлять флешки в порт - разбиваются порты, что приводит к их ремонту и затратам. У нас имеется USB-hab на 30 портов. Но винда видит не более 10-ти, и она их определяет на свое усмотрение, то одни, то другие, может повторять... и остальные при этом не доступны. А нам нужно обращаться к той или иной флешке, которая необходима в данный момент, и при этом не дергать их туда-сюда по портам. Вот - уперлись в ограничение винды. А как это настроить или исправить - не знаем